# Remove all NSLogs in Xcode at once

Tags: xcode, logging

Am currently creating a demo drawing and image editing app just for a practice. Have created few custom views and doing my drawings using draw rect. Thing is i keep writing NSLogs to check my points and contents of other objects frequently and i dont remove many of them, since i need them again and again. But observing that the logs are eating up processing time and making some of the drawing process laggy.

*My question is, is there any method in xcode to remove all NSlogs at once while launching the app and add them again while testing.*

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this...

Click  `Command`+`Shift`+`F`

Select `Replace`

[image]

And replace `NSLog` with `//NSLog`

Not so good solution, but still works! :)

Comment: Yes, one more hint that change `Hits must` from `contain search term` to `start with search term` this would help when you need to change from NSLog to //NSLog incase there exist some //NSLog already

Comment: oh cool, thx again for the extra info, but i think this would also uncomment out the intentionally converted NSLogs, when you want to revert back to testing using NSLogs..

Comment: No, as I commented above you should change to `start with search term` which would change all the nslogs in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Hi One method that i came to know is using the **Find and replace** option in xcode.
ie. say for eg you need to remove all NSLogs you have written in your entire project.
Find for the **NSLog keyword** in whole project **(cmd+shift+F)**, then replace it with ***//NSLog***. This would ***comment*** out all the NSLogs you have written.
When you need to uncomment the logs just do the opposite.
ie Find for the **//NSLog keyword** in whole project **(cmd+shift+F)**, then replace it with ***NSLog***. This would *uncomment* out all the NSLogs you have written and they print in the console again. 
You can do this for particular files also by using just (cmd+F) instead of (cmd+shift+F).. 
But not sure if xcode actually has a proper method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

found one more good way of doing it, by defining your custom NSLog, using a macro like this:
  MYLog(@"Count of student array-->%d",[studentArray count]);

*And in your **app-prefix.h** file, which holds the common headers for all your files in the project define the **'MYLog' macro** this way:-*

#ifdef DEBUG

#define MYLog(f, ...) NSLog( @"<%@:(%d)> %@",[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:**_FILE** _] lastPathComponent], **_LINE** _, [NSString stringWithFormat:(f), ##**_VA_ARGS** _] )

#else

#define MYLog(f, ...)

#endif

So when you need to test, put your project in debug mode and when you need to run without the logs put your project in release mode. Simple.. 
ps FILE AND LINE are macros executed py the preprocessor to print the file name and line no in which the log is present. Try it out..